# Loading multiple views asynchronous in swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I was wondering how someone would load multiple UI elements asynchronously. In my case, I have a `UIViewController` that has a `UISegmentControl`. Each segment has different UI aspects to load.
For example `seg1` shows one image, `seg2` shows and image and some text, etc.

If I load all the UI elements before showing the `UIViewController` then there is a noticeable lag. So I would want to load `seg2...n` asynchronously to make the UI feel more responsive.

Would I need to load everything via

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    // load UI
}
```

For each `seg` I want to load in the background? Or can I load these elements on another thread and not take up the main thread? I know you're not supposed to update the UI on background threads... But will using the main thread still block the UI if I use async code?

Comment: Simply invoking "DispatchQueue.main.asyn" simply takes that closure and marshals it to the end of the queue ... if you have a long running/indeterminate-length operation you will still block the GUI.  You will have simply waited a couple of additional milliseconds to do it.

Isn't it possible to take the various resources that are the true cause of the extra time, and handle them on a background thread?  Try setting the QOS (quality of service to a high value to help).

Comment: Oh I see. Use the profiler to see what actually takes time and do those in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make UI changes on a background thread. Nearly all UIKit calls must be made on the main thread. Therefore you're likely out of luck.

Instead what you should do is do the time consuming number-crunching (downloading and parsing data for example) on a background thread and then use DispatchQueue.main.async() to install the data into your views on the main thread once the time consuming work is done.

If it's the UI setup that is introducing the lag and it's not possible to speed it up then you may be out of luck.